# How to make this search and count much faster?

Tags: python, list, search

```
def count_occurrences(string):
    count = 0
    for text in GENERIC_TEXT_STORE:
        count += text.count(string)
    return count
```

GENERIC_TEXT_STORE is a list of string. For example:

```
GENERIC_TEXT_STORE = ['this is good', 'this is a test', 'that's not a test']
```

Given a string 'text', I want to find how many times the text, i.e. 'this', occurs in the GENERIC_TEXT_STORE.  If my GENERIC_TEXT_STORE is huge, this is very slow. What are the ways to make this search and count much faster? For instance, if I split the big GENERIC_TEXT_STORE list into multiple smaller lists, would that be faster?

If the multiprocessing module is useful here, how to make it possible for this purpose?

Comment: Is your function supposed to count words only (e.g. `is`, `good`, `not`, `that's`), or is it supposed to count substrings (e.g. `is g`, `tha`, `t a tes`, `good`)?

Comment: I'll second the request to please clarify your requirements. If you search the same big string collection many times, and the `string` argument is always a word, you can store the collection as a dict of word counts. If the `string` could be an arbitrary substring like *"rbitrary s"* maybe look at storing it as a trie. If you only search `GENERIC_STRING_STORE` once before its value changes, I don't think your code can be easily improved in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re`.

```
In [2]: GENERIC_TEXT_STORE = ['this is good', 'this is a test', 'that\'s not a test']

In [3]: def count_occurrences(string):
   ...:     count = 0
   ...:     for text in GENERIC_TEXT_STORE:
   ...:         count += text.count(string)
   ...:     return count

In [6]: import re

In [7]: def count(_str):
   ...:     return len(re.findall(_str,''.join(GENERIC_TEXT_STORE)))
   ...:
In [28]: def count1(_str):
    ...:     return ' '.join(GENERIC_TEXT_STORE).count(_str)
    ...:
```

---

Now using `timeit` to analyse the execution time.

when size of `GENERIC_TEXT_STORE` is `3`.

```
In [9]: timeit count('this')
1.27 µs ± 57.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [10]: timeit count_occurrences('this')
697 ns ± 25.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [33]: timeit count1('this')
385 ns ± 22.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

when size of `GENERIC_TEXT_STORE` is  `15000`.

```
In [17]: timeit count('this')
1.07 ms ± 118 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [18]: timeit count_occurrences('this')
3.35 ms ± 279 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [37]: timeit count1('this')
275 µs ± 18.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

when size of `GENERIC_TEXT_STORE` is `150000`

```
In [20]: timeit count('this')
5.7 ms ± 2.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [21]: timeit count_occurrences('this')
33 ms ± 3.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [40]: timeit count1('this')
3.98 ms ± 211 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

when size of `GENERIC_TEXT_STORE` is over a million (`1500000`)

```
In [23]: timeit count('this')
50.3 ms ± 7.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [24]: timeit count_occurrences('this')
283 ms ± 12.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [43]: timeit count1('this')
40.7 ms ± 1.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

> *count1 < count < count_occurrences*

When the size of `GENERIC_TEXT_STORE` is large `count` and `count1` are almost 4 to 5 times faster than `count_occurrences`.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that your algorithm is actually doing what you want, as suggested in the comments above. The count() method is checking for substring equality, you could probably get a big improvement by refactoring your code to test only complete words assuming that's what you want. Something like this could work as your condition.

```
any((word==string for word in text.split()))
```

Multiprocessing would probably help as you could split the list into smaller lists (one per core) then add up all the results when each process finishes (avoid inter-process communication during the execution). I've found from testing that multi-processing in Python varies quite a bit between operating systems, Windows and Mac can take quite a long time to actually spawn the processes whereas Linux seems to do it much faster. Some people have said that setting a CPU affinity for each process using pstools is important but I didn't find this made much difference in my case.

Another answer would be to look at using Cython to compile your Python into a C program or alternatively rewrite the whole thing in a faster language, but as you've tagged this answer Python I assume you're not so keen on that.

Comment: If the search is word-based rather than substring-based (and depending on the exact use case) one could also preprocess the information and build an index where each word points to a list of substrings it appears in.